# Short postgres function for regex check

Tags: postgresql

The definition below seems heavy for what it does. Can this be written more succinctly?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "check_email"(email TEXT)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN email ~* '^[A-Za-z0-9._%+$-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+([.][A-Za-z0-9-]+)+$';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am not interested in shortening the regex, just the definition boilerplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL instead of PLPGSQL language:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_email(text)
RETURNS boolean AS $$
    SELECT $1 ~* '^[A-Za-z0-9._%+$-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+([.][A-Za-z0-9-]+)+$';
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```